# C++ Data Structure_mystack.pop() & myqueue.serve() infinite loop of eof()

Tags: c++, data-structures, infinite-loop

This code has infinite loop on `pop()` and `serve()`. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

This code has infinite loop on `pop()` and `serve()`. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

This code has infinite loop on `pop()` and `serve()`. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Queue myqueue;
    Stack mystack;

    ifstream inputFile;
    string fileName;

    cout << "Enter the file name you would like to use with file type e.g. data.txt: ";

    cin >> fileName;
    inputFile.open(fileName);

    string name;
    int value;

    cout << "Operation" << "\t" << "Stack" << "\t" << "Value" << "\t" << "Result" "\n";
    cout << "------------------------------------------\n";

    inputFile >> name >> value;

    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
        if (name == "push")
        {
            cout << name << "\t" << "\t" << "stack" << "\t" << value << "\t" << "success" << endl;
            inputFile >> name >> value;
            mystack.Push(value);
        }
        else if (name == "pop")
        {
            if (mystack.IsEmpty() == true)
            {
                cout << name << "\t" << "\t" << "stack" << "\t" << "---" << "\t" << "underflow" << endl;
            }
            else if (mystack.IsEmpty() == false)
            {
                cout << name << "\t" << "\t" << "stack" << "\t" << "---" << "\t" << "success" << endl;
            }
            inputFile >> name >> value;
            mystack.Pop(value);
            break;
        }
        else if (name == "append")
        {
            cout << name << "\t" << "\t" << "stack" << "\t" << value << "\t" << "success" << endl;
            inputFile >> name >> value;
            myqueue.append(value);
        }
        else if (name == "serve")
        {
            if (myqueue.IsEmpty() == true)
            {
                cout << name << "\t" << "\t" << "stack" << "\t" << "---" << "\t" << "underflow" << endl;
            }
            else if (myqueue.IsEmpty() == false)
            {
                cout << name << "\t" << "\t" << "stack" << "\t" << "---" << "\t" << "success" << endl;
            }
            inputFile >> name >> value;
            myqueue.serve(value);
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Stack" << endl;
    cout << "-------" << endl;
    mystack.Print();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Queue" << endl;
    cout << "-------" << endl;
    myqueue.Print();

    inputFile.close();
    cout << endl;

    system("Pause");
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------
// serve data from the queue.
//-----------------------------------------------------------
void Queue::serve(int &item)
{
    // Check if empty
    if (IsEmpty())
        cout << "underflow\n";

    // serve data
    else
    {
        item = Data[Front];
        Front = (Front + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
        Count--;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Pop data from the stack.
//-----------------------------------------------------------
void Stack::Pop(int &Number)
{
    // Check for empty stack
    if (IsEmpty())
        return;

    // Extract information from node
    Number = Head->Number;

    // Pop item from linked list
    SNode *Temp = Head;
    Head = Head->Next;
    delete Temp;
    Length--;

    // cout << "Pop " << Number << endl;
}

<Stack>
bool Stack::IsEmpty()
{
    return (Length == 0);
}

<Queue>
bool Queue::IsEmpty()
{
    return (Count <= 0);
}
```

Comment: If you don't send the code from myqueue and mystack, I don't see how anyone can help you...

Comment: Guess: you are reading a blank line at the end of the file, your "else if" doesn't manage the case and you stay in an infinite loop

Comment: 2nd: Improve your use case. The description of your analysis let me think your code hits often in the "pop" and "serve" branch of the code: but in these branch there is a break statement that stops the while execution...could you be more clear?

Comment: How is the method "IsEmpty" implemented in both structure?

Comment: I put break; because of the infinite loop. When I delete them and the data has pop or serve, it was a infinite loop.